# std::function const correctness not followed

Tags: c++, constants, std-function

I was surprised to find this code compiles:

```
#include <functional>

struct Callable {
    void operator() () { count++; }
    void operator() () const = delete;
    int count = 0;
};

int main() {
    const Callable counter;
    // counter(); //error: use of deleted function 'void Callable::operator()() const'
    std::function<void(void)> f = counter;
    f();

    const auto cf = f;
    cf();

}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/FH3PoiYewklxmiXl

This will call the non-const call operator of `Callable`. Comparatively, if you do `const auto cf = counter; cf();` then it errors out as expected. So, why does const correctness not seem to be followed with `std::function`?

Comment: I think you are confused with what is const and what is not. Your declaration doesn't make `counter` const, which is the one that has the `const=delete`.

Comment: Why do you expect the `const` version to be called?

Answer (score 5):

`std::function` adds a layer of indirection, and this layer of indirection does not pass through `const`ness to the callable.

I'm not really sure why this is — probably because `std::function` takes a copy of the callable and has no need to keep the copy `const` (in fact this might break assignment semantics) — I'm also not really sure why you'd need it to.

(Of course, directly invoking `operator()` on an object of a type that you just so happened to call `Callable` and declared as `const` will require a `const` context, as it would with any other object.)

Best practice is to give the callable a `const` `operator()` and leave it at that.

*tl;dr: true, but not a bug, and doesn't matter*

Answer (score 4):

You are correct to find this weird. The call operator of `std::function` is marked `const` but the `const`ness is not propagated when the target object is actually invoked. The proposal [p0045r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0045r1.pdf) seems to remedy this by making the call operator of `std::function` non-const but allowing the following syntax:

```
std::function<return_type(arg_type) const>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that assigning `counter` to `std::function` object creates a copy of `counter`.

In your case, `f` is initialized using the following constructor:

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

As described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), this constructor *"initializes the target with std::move(f)"* - a new object of type `Callable` is created and initialized using copy constructor.

If you'd like to initialize `f` with a reference to `counter` instead, you can use `std::ref`:

```
std::function<void()> f = std::ref(counter);
```

`std::ref` returns an instance of `std::reference_wrapper`, which has [`operator ()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()), which calls `Callable`'s `operator () const`. As expected, you'll get an error, since that operator is deleted.